# How can i submit a PHP form without redirect to action file? (send and get data with ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, action

I load a form by click on a button with $("#btn").load("form.php") in index.php,
I want to avoid redirect the page to action file after submit and add an item in the table which is under the form.

my demo is on http://price.parag.website

```
<?php include "../connection.php" ?>

<h1>Add CPU</h1>

<form method="post" action="actions/cpu_action.php">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpu_name" />
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpu_price" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, cpu_name, cpu_price FROM cpu";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>CPU NAME</th>
    <th>CPU PRICE</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cpu_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cpu_price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: why you didn't use ajax?

Comment: The question is unclear. The title says "without redirect", but the text says "force redirect". Which do you really want to do?

Comment: There are many tutorials on using AJAX to submit a form without reloading the page.

Comment: i want submit form without redirect to action file

Comment: There are answers in Stack Overflow about how to submit form without reloading in PHP. Technically, your question does not show any research effort.

Comment: ajax is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h1>Add CPU</h1>

<form id="formupload" method="post" action="actions/cpu_action.php">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpu_name" />
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpu_price" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

now we have to clear default action of form (i will use jquery)

```
     $('#formupload').on('submit',function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
         var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: $('#formupload').attr('action'),
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(result){
         if(condition){}
         else{}
    }
    })
   })
```

Try this it will work

Comment: it's work bro! thanks a lot... but I have a new question???
after added item table doesn't reload automatically... I actually add this code 
`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");`
in a PHP file and include it to PHP form page... I think it's the cause of that my form is loaded by .load("")...

Comment: use load() into function and fetch data from another php page and append it to specific element and call that function in success ajax response..

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
```

```js
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "pageToPost.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("data1=bar&data2=foo");
}
</script>
```

This will take the response and update the element with id `table` with the repsonse, so make sure that it is in html.

Comment: i have used ajax call actually, removing method will lead to  default method as "Get"

Comment: OK, so something like what I have just edited to be?

Comment: @FrazAbbas just change POST to GET and remove the params in send to add onto the end of ```pageToPost.php``` like a normal url GET request.